# c# - difference between Button and System.Windows.Forms.Button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

In my form1 class I have a number of buttons added using the designer. ie button1, button2.etc

In my controller class I've created an array of buttons like:

```
Btns[k,m] = new Button();
```

then go:

```
Btns[1,1].Name = "button1";
Btns[1,1].Visible = False;
```

But this does not actually change the visibility of the button on my form class. Does anyone know why?

Basically create an array of button names in the controller that actually link to the form buttons in my form1 class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between `Button` and `System.Windows.Forms.Button` assuming you are `using` `System.Windows.Forms` and there is no ambiguity.

Don't overwrite `Btns[k, m]` with a new button. That is, remove this line:

```
Btns[k, m] = new Button();
```

If `Btns` is not set from the designer and would have its elements be `null`, set them to the buttons created from the designer:

```
Btns[1, 1] = button1;
```

Comment: I tried that but then at runtime the following line 'Btns[1,1].Visible = False;'  threw an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: ok i worked that out. Now is there anyway of going: String varb = "button" + k; Btns[1, 1] = varb;   ?

Comment: @toop: `(Button)this.GetType().GetField("button" + k).GetValue(this)`

Answer (score 0):

The Button class in .Net framework comes under the System.Windows.Forms package. By default this is already referenced in Windows Form Applications. In C# you will see

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

at the top of the code behind of any form. If it is VB.Net you may not see

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

as in C# but if you go to the references in solution explorer you will see that the reference is already there.

Since you have the references already there is no difference of just typing Button or System.Windows.Forms.Button. If you use the System.Windows.Forms we can say that it's like the full qualified path.

For example think of one particular class room, (Let's say Grade 11 class A) in a school and take one student who's name is David and imagine you also in the same class room. So if you want to refer him you will simply call his name David.Now think you are in a different class and you want to refer him. So in this case just calling David won't enough to identify him. You have to say something like this."David from Grade 11 Class A". Now again think if you both in the same class and when you want to refer him and it's look bit dumb if you call him "David from Grade 11 Class A" instead of just using David.

So if you are in the same class(=> you have the using System.Windows.Forms already defined) and want to refer David(=> Button) just saying Button is enough else you can use System.Windows.Forms.Button.

Hope you'll get some idea.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I believe the main difference would be one required to process a form and the other could be used as initiator / hyperlink mask

Comment: I can't really understand why you have Btns[k,m]??

Comment: it is used for the 2d array Btns, don't think it is relevant to the core of the question though.